# Getting data from an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Given the following array of hashes:

```
[{name: "joe", age: 21}, {name: "mary", age: 32}, {name: "mark", age: 25}]
```

How can I get an array of names returned, like this:

```
["joe","mary","mark"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using [`#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)

```
arr = [{name: "joe", age: 21}, {name: "mary", age: 32}, {name: "mark", age: 25}]
arr.map { |x| x[:name] }
# => ["joe", "mary", "mark"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`Array#collect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-collect) method

```
ary_of_hash = [{name: "joe", age: 21}, {name: "mary", age: 32}, {name: "mark", age: 25}]
ary_of_hash.collect { |hash| hash[:name] }
```

Answer (score -3):

I think **map** solves the problem.

```
[{name: "joe", age: 21}, {name: "mary", age: 32}, {name: "mark", age: 25}].map(function(node){return node.name});

// returns ["joe", "mary", "mark"]
```

[<kbd>Reference and fallback</kbd>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  for `.map()`

Comment: this is the way how we use map in JS. 'function' is argument for map function which accepts node as first arg here which refers the current element of the array while looping it.

Comment: The question is tagged `ruby` so answering with javascript is confusing, particularly when ruby has it's own `map` function with different syntax.

Comment: oops... I dint see the tag